# Make sync method in Meteor js

Tags: meteor, synchronization, future

I tried to make a sync method according to https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/synchronous-methods

Here's my code:
Server side

```
Meteor.methods({
    sendDataToMixer: function(){

        var Future = require('fibers/future');
        var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
        var future = new Future();

        var ssh = new SSH({
            host: 'host',
            user: 'user',
            pass: 'pass'
        });

        ssh
        .exec('mkdir check133', {
          out: console.log.bind(console)
        })
        .start({
            success: function(){
                future.return("success!");
                console.log(future);
            },
            error: function(err){
                future.return(err);
            }
        });

    return future.wait();
 }
});
```

Client side:

```
Meteor.call('sendDataToMixer', function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Ooops from future');

                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log('clicked');
                    }
                });
```

But this solution doesn't work as a sync one. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What  you got in response , i mean how you are checking that method is running synchronously or not?

Comment: @Parveenyadav I check it out by the answer of a callback function. Guess, it was my mistake, cause callback is always async. So I should just set a Future and then call a method without callback, right? (I read that Meteor.apply with wait flag and Meteor.call will run sync if callback function isn't set)